# Increase the resolution in a step function using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

I have an array which consists in a delta function (either 0 or 1). I use this function to generate a step function array by applying a forward-fill algorithm. This array is the one I need for a certain operation.

This plot displays the delta and step arrays:

[image]

However, I need to increase the resolution of this array to perform the operation. However, I cannot directly apply something like numpy.interp

[image]

which distorts the original functions.

Hence my question would be which is the efficient (and pythonic way) to increase the resolution in a step function?

This is an example script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def forward_filling(arr):
    idx=np.where(arr==0,0,np.arange(len(arr)))    
    idx=np.maximum.accumulate(idx)    
    return arr[idx]

fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, 1)  

x_array = np.arange(0, 15)
y_delta = np.zeros(len(x_array))
y_delta[3], y_delta[7], y_delta[13] = 1, 2, 3
step_function = forward_filling(y_delta)

axis.plot(x_array, y_delta, label='delta function', marker='o')
axis.plot(x_array, step_function, label='step function')

x_high_resolution = np.linspace(0, 15, 30)

delta_interpolated  = np.interp(x_high_resolution, x_array, y_delta)
step_interpolated   = np.interp(x_high_resolution, x_array, step_function)

axis.plot(x_high_resolution, delta_interpolated, label='delta function high resolution', marker='o')
axis.plot(x_high_resolution, step_interpolated, label='step function high resolution')

axis.legend()

axis.set_xlabel('x')
axis.set_ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suppose you would like to maintain the y value in the neighbourhood of each given y value, you could "substitute" each y-value for, say, 3 of the same values using a List Comprehension:

```
step_function_hi_res = np.array([np.repeat(step,3) for step in step_function]).flatten()
```

and then make the changes in your x-values as you already did:

```
x_high_resolution = np.linspace(0, len(step_function),len(step_function)*3)
```